# How to make restapi call from jasmine-protractor for non-angular app

Tags: rest, jasmine, protractor

I am using jasmine-protractor e2e framework to test one of our desktop App. I am totally new to this. So if something is not clear please ask.

This is how I am logging in to the server. Server uses SSO for authentication

```
describe('Protractor', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
  browser.get('https://myserver.com/login.html',60000);   
});


it('hi', function () {
  var btn = element(by.css('.loginFormGroup')).element(by.partialLinkText('Tegile'));
  btn.click();
  // browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  var user = element(by.css('.UsernamePasswordTable')).element(By.id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox'));
  user.sendKeys('user');

  var pass = element(by.css('.UsernamePasswordTable')).element(By.id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordTextBox'));
  pass.sendKeys('passwd');

  var SignIn = element(by.css('.UsernamePasswordTable')).element(By.id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SubmitButton'));
  // browser.pause();
  SignIn.click();
});
```

After this i would like to execute restapi on the same server. I want it to use same session if possible.

I tried to use request/request, but didnt work. Maybe i was not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use nodejs `http` module to make API calls.Look at below examples on how to make both GET and POST calls using http module.

**GET call:**

```
var http = require('http');

var headerObj = { Cookie : 'cookie-value' }
var options = {
            host: "localhost" ,
            path: "/someurl",
            port: 8080,
            headers : headerObj
        };
 var req=  http.request(options,function(response) {
                var body = '';
                response.on('data', function(d) {
                    body += d;
                });
                response.on('end', function() {
                  console.log(body);
                });

            }).on('error', function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

            req.end();
```

**POST call:**

```
  var http = require('http');

  var data = { name : "somename" }; //data that need to be posted.
  var options = {
            "method": "POST",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "port": 8080,
            "path": "/someurl",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                cookie: 'cookie-value'
            }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            var body = '';

            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                body = body + chunk;
            });

            res.on("end", function () {
              console.log(body);
            });
        });

        req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        req.end();
```

Comment: How do I get value of cookie. Also in above example where username and password are passed for authentication.

Comment: also data is not always hashref. its arrayref which in turn might have hashref as its elements

Answer (score 1):

I used SuperAgent to make REST API calls for my application,
below is the link describes the usage of superagent.

[npm package superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent)

Comment: it seems to be working for me.It worked for app which uses Basic authentication.I have one more desktop app which uses SSO for logging in. So it redirects to auth server and after auth is complete, it will redirect back to the app server. I use protractor to login to app server, which is working fine. After logging in I want to execute some restapi on same server. Since I have already logged in to server, is there a way to use same browser session to execute restapi on it. I am asking this because I dont know how to authenticate this server using restapi. Let me know if something is not clear.